# Angular list detail view with firebase autogenerated id

Tags: angularjs, view, firebase, parameter-passing, ionic-framework

I'm trying to load some names from a firebase to my list view and then when I click on any of the items it shows the name on the next view using the autogenerated id inside firebase for the respective name. Here's my code:

controllers.js:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {
  var listAllUsers=function(){
    UserService.listAll().then(function(users){
        $scope.list=users;
    });
  }

  listAllUsers();
})

.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, UserService) {

    UserService.listById($stateParams.listId).then(function(user){
      $scope.user=user;
    });
    console.log($stateParams.listId);


});
```

services.js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('UserService', function($q, $firebaseArray) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://list-detail-001.firebaseIO.com/users')

    var Users=$firebaseArray(ref);

    return {
        listAll:function(){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(Users);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        listById:function(userId){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
            var user=Users[userId];
            deferred.resolve(user);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

list.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Lists">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="listitem in list" href="#/{{listitem.$id}}">
        {{listitem.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

detail.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Details">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>{{user.title}}</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

As you can see, the app is fairly simple. The data works if its in a simple json array, but I cannot seem to get the details page to just display the user.title property. I'm probably missing something really simple. Can anyone please help? I'm guessing the issue in my code has to do with either the listById() function in my services.js or my DetailCtrl in my  controller.js. But I don't know what. I'm getting the correct ID from my database in the $stateParams.listId parameter but from there on, my $scope.users is undefined. Please help!

Comment: I've never done Ionic, but based on Angular experience I'd expect an `ng-click` handler somewhere (or from a very quick glance at the ionic site a `ion-option-button`). Is that missing from your code? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

Comment: Not that I know of. The app works just fine. Clicking on items on the list automatically opens the page and even passes the key Value of the record to the next page but I cannot access the data related to it any more.

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird. Does the `console.log($stateParams.listId);` in your `DetailCtrl` print anything?

Comment: Yes it does. It actually gives me the correct key. I'm guessing the userService.listById function is not working with that information correctly.

Comment: Why are we artificially wrapping $firebaseArray in this useless listAll/listById construct? Just return the array and use the already available API. Note that your listById method won't work because it's trying to use a user id on an array (which has numeric indices). Try $getRecord(userId) instead. Or better, don't add complexity without any gain and get rid of these methods.

Comment: Ah I see! If I were to take away the complexity of the codes, what would my scripts look like please? Please strip it down for me. I'm really new to this. I'm taking code from all over and customizing it for my app so I'm not sure how to simplify it yet. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed the issue. Now everything works. I wanted to keep the promises because I'm a bit paranoid and I don't want a situation where my data is large, and my UI suffers becasue of it.

controllers.js:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, UserService) {
  var listAllUsers=function(){
    UserService.listAll().then(function(users){
        $scope.list=users;
    });
  }

  listAllUsers();
})

.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, UserService) {

    UserService.listById($stateParams.listId).then(function(user){
      $scope.user=user;
    });
});
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('UserService', function($q, $firebaseArray,$firebaseObject) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://list-detail-001.firebaseIO.com/users')

    var Users=$firebaseArray(ref);

    return {
        listAll:function(){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(Users);
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        listById:function(key){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
            var userRef= ref.child(key);
            var user=$firebaseObject(userRef);
            deferred.resolve(user);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```