# Ionic Master Detail view with Firebase auto-generated child key returning JSON $value null

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, master-detail

I am new to Ionic and Firebase. While fetching data for details view I am getting undefined value for `$scope.program`.

However, I have fetched the complete programs list in Master view. Clicking the list item from master view returns index (0, 1, 2, etc) of the list in console log but not the child key (which I was expecting)

During my research, I found out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538962/6947898) quite relevant to my problem, by [Wes Haq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3068930/wes-haq). But while implementing the same, it has no change in the result. Please help.

From the above question by Wes Haq, I couldn't find the state provider details. I may be missing something there. Thanks in advance to all.

controllers.js

```
 
    
    .controller('myServicesCtrl', ['$scope', '$state',     '$stateParams',      '$ionicActionSheet', 'AgencyProgService', 
      function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicActionSheet,    AgencyProgService) {
             //Only items relative to the logged/signed in Agency shall be     pushed to the scope.items
              $scope.programs = AgencyProgService.getPrograms();
       }])


    .controller('serviceDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'AgencyProgService', 
     function ($scope, $stateParams, AgencyProgService) {
     AgencyProgService.getProgram($stateParams.index).then(function     (program) {
                 $scope.program = program;
             });
             console.log("serviceDetailCtrl: scope.program is: " +         $scope.program);
        }])
```

service.js

```
 

    .service('AgencyProgService', ['$q', '$firebaseArray',     '$firebaseObject', 'AgencyDataService', function ($q, $firebaseArray,     $firebaseObject, AgencyDataService) {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('programs/'); // this is     a valid ref with https://my-demo.firebaseio.com/programs
       var agencyIDfromPrograms = AgencyDataService.getAgencyUID();
       var refFilter =    ref.orderByChild("agencyID").equalTo(agencyIDfromPrograms);
       return {
          getPrograms: function () {
           return $firebaseArray(refFilter);
         },

          getProgram: function (programId) {
          console.log("getProgram: ID is: " + programId + "And refFilter to     use is: " + ref);

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var programRef = ref.child(programId); // here programId should     be the autogenerated child key from fire DB "programs"
            var program = $firebaseObject(programRef);
            deferred.resolve(program);
            return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
      }])
```

Views:
myServices.html

```
    <ion-list id="myServices-list9">
            <ion-item id="myServices-list-item11" 
                ng-repeat="item in programs" ui-    sref="serviceDetail({index: $index})">
                <div class="item-thumbnail-left">
                    <i class="icon"></i>
                    <h2>{{item.progName}} </h2>
                    <p>{{item.servType}} for: {{item.servHours}}</p>
                    <p>From: {{item.servStartDate}}</p>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

serviceDetail.html

```
<div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
            <img src="{{item.user.picture.thumbnail}} " />
            <h1>{{program.servContact}}</h1>
            <h2>{{program.$id}} {{program.progName}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.servContact}} {{item.servStartDate}}</p>

</div>
<pre> {{program | json}} </pre>
```

From serviceDetail view, no data from `program` is visible, as you can see from the screen shot below. List card for `serviceDetail`. on clicking 2nd item on `myServices`, it shows this detail screen with `$id` as `1`. Expected is the child key for programs:

[image: 2]

Firebase data structure screenshot for child programs is as below,

[image: child from programs DB on Firebase]

Appreciate your suggestions.